# SharePoint Online, customer's Sites

Tags: external-users, extranet, collaboration

I have an Office 365 E3 license that comes with SharePoint online.

Is there any way to create separate Sites for each of my customers within my own account, in a way only each of them can see their own information and no one else's?

I would like that they dont even see the names or sites of any other customers I have.
I have only 7 customers, small businesses, and each customer has 2-4 people that would need to see my site, some of them read only and some of them read/write.
4 of them customers use Office 365 as well, and 3 of them has their own email server.

Answer (score 0):

easier is to give each customer a new site collection. This will give you complete control on the security. The same can be achieved using sites also but site collection gives you more control in themes, etc.

Comment: I wanted to start from scratch, and delete the test site I just added, so I can add a site collection,, but I cant delete the site. Im the SharePoint owner and the button for "delete" is not on the site settings. 
Im trying to follow instructions on:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Delete-a-site-team-site-or-subsite-in-Office-365-bc37b743-0cef-475e-9a8c-8fc4d40179fb
but I dont see the options like they are shown. All these apps change so quick ! and they render the previous documentation and instructions out of date !

Comment: That is bit unlikely to happen! If you have SharePoint administrator role on the tenant, you can delete the site collection from the admin portal. If you are not at liberty to delete site collection, you make sure to get yourself explicitly set as the site collection administrator. Then you will be able to delete any site you want in it.